# Word Find and Replace: Search for any month

Tags: ms-word

For a MS Word document, I need to find all occurrences of any month name and replace it with a generic place older. How can I do that with the `Find and Replace` function?

i.e., How can I search a Word document for every occurance of `January` `February` `March` `April` `...` etc.

I can do this for one month at a time, but would like to do it for any month in a single action.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's not a programming question.

Nevertheless, you can use a *wildcard* Find/Replace where:

```
Find = <[JFMASOND][abceghilmnoprstuvy]{2,8}>
Replace = [MONTH]
```

**Note:** The above will find abbreviated months also. There is also a small risk of mis-matches if you have capitalized words in the document that the expression can match. For example, 'May' may or may not be a month, whilst 'Feminine' is never a month. If you pair the Find with a day and/or year, you'll eliminate the risk of mis-matches. For example:

```
Find = <[JFMASOND][abceghilmnoprstuvy]{2,8}( [0-9]{1,4}>)
Replace = [MONTH]/1
```

will find a month name followed by a day or year number, whilst retaining that number in the replacement.

Comment: Thanks! I tried so many different wildcard expressions without luck (Word doesn't appear to have an OR operator like regular expression does), but I knew someone here would know how to do this. That second example is very helpful.